# mateo ...javascript

Tags: javascript, comparison, element

hi what happens is that I am making an Enrollment Form, and I have a text field where I need 2 comparisons, I assess the number of ICFES snp, and if prior to 2000 has 12 digits, and after the 2000 14 ... and I've tried and nothing ... restricts me when I'm older than 14.

```
function verificar(valor) {
    var letras=document.form1.snp.value;
    var long=letras.length;

    //alert(long);
    if(letras.length==2)
    {
        dp=letras;
    }
    numeros=letras.charAt(2);
    //alert (numeros);
    if(dp!="ac" && dp!="av"  ) {
        document.getElementById("materias").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("puntaje").style.display="none";
    }
    else if (long==12 && long==14)
    {
        //alert ("el numero del icfes no es correcto"); 
        document.getElementById("materias").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("puntaje").style.display="none";
    }
   else if(dp=="ac" || dp=="av") {
       if(long==12 && numeros!=2)
       { 
           document.getElementById("materias").style.display="none";
           document.getElementById("puntaje").style.display="block";
       }
       if(numeros==2)
       {
           if(long==14)
           { 
               document.getElementById("materias").style.display="block";
               document.getElementById("puntaje").style.display="none";
           }
       }

   }
}
```

You have my appreciation if you can help me.

Comment: The code is readable. Can someone maybe help out? I did an automated translation

Comment: Hi what happens is that I am making an Enrollment Form, and I have a text field where I need 2 comparisons, I assess the number of *ICFES snp*, and if prior to 2000 has 12 digits, and after the 2000 14 digits ... and I've tried and nothing ... restricts me when I'm older than 14. <see code> You have my appreciation if you can help me.

Comment: translation from original Spanish not guaranteed  ;-)  See the edit history if you are willing & able to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could use modern JS (first two lines of the function):

```
var letraselem=document.getElementById("snp");
var letras=letraselem.value;
```

instead of:

```
var letras=document.form1.snp.value;
```

snp must be set as id of the desired element